# Python and encoding, again

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have the next code snippet in Python (2.7.8) on Windows:

```
text1 = 'áéíóú'
text2 = text1.encode("utf-8")
```

and i have the next error exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to specify that you are dealing with a unicode string:

```
text1 = u'áéíóú'  #prefix string with "u"
text2 = text1.encode("utf-8")
```

In python 3 this behavior has changed, and any string is unicode, so you don't need to specify it.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan - You should try it once.

Comment: @J19 You're welcome :) I've noticed you're not usually accepting answers. On SO, it's customary to mark a answer as accepted if it solves your issue, so other people can quickly figure out the solution. To mark an answer as accepted, click the checkmark left of the answer text

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan No problem. I've added some info to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code in Linux with Python 2.7:

```
>>> text1 = 'áéíóú'
>>> text1
'\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa9\xc3\xad\xc3\xb3\xc3\xba'
>>> type(text1)
<type 'str'>
>>> text1.decode("utf-8")
u'\xe1\xe9\xed\xf3\xfa'
>>> print '\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa9\xc3\xad\xc3\xb3\xc3\xba'
áéíóú
>>> print u'\xe1\xe9\xed\xf3\xfa'
áéíóú
>>> u'\xe1\xe9\xed\xf3\xfa'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa9\xc3\xad\xc3\xb3\xc3\xba'
```

`\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa9\xc3\xad\xc3\xb3\xc3\xba` is  the utf-8 coding of `áéíóú`. And `\xe1\xe9\xed\xf3\xfa` is the unicode coding of `áéíóú`.

`text1` is encoded by utf-8, it only can be **decoded** to unicode by:

```
text1.decode("utf-8")
```

an unicode string can be encoded to an utf-8 string:

```
u'\xe1\xe9\xed\xf3\xfa'.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This is a good explanation of the process, but please notice **there's no such thing as a "unicode coding"**. Unicode is just a number table, not a encoding. `\xe1\xe9\xed\xf3\xfa` is actually [`latin-1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)